# VB.Net Background gradient using LinearGradientBrush and display Image

Tags: vb.net, forms, graphics

I try to achieve to paint a form with a gradient backcolor and overlap an image with transparency.

This is possible?

I want using a tile background image with transparent background and paint the background with a custom linear gradient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do it!, I want share my solution with you (It's pretty easy):

External help: [Tile a Shape with an Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/729d4sbe.aspx)

```
Private Sub BackgroundGradient(ByRef Control As Object, _
                                ByVal Color1 As Drawing.Color, _
                                ByVal Color2 As Drawing.Color)

    Dim vLinearGradient As Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush = _
        New Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(New Drawing.Point(Control.Width, Control.Height), _
                                                    New Drawing.Point(Control.Width, 0), _
                                                    Color1, _
                                                    Color2)

    Dim vGraphic As Drawing.Graphics = Control.CreateGraphics
    ' To tile the image background - Using the same image background of the image
    Dim vTexture As New Drawing.TextureBrush(Control.BackgroundImage)

    vGraphic.FillRectangle(vLinearGradient, Control.DisplayRectangle)
    vGraphic.FillRectangle(vTexture, Control.DisplayRectangle)

    vGraphic.Dispose() : vGraphic = Nothing : vTexture.Dispose() : vTexture = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to draw the gradient background. Tiling the image will be slow unless you use the windows API or something.

```
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class frmBG

  Private Sub frmBG_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim p1 As Point = Me.ClientRectangle.Location
    Dim p2 As Point = New Point(Me.ClientRectangle.Right, Me.ClientRectangle.Bottom)
    Using brsGradient As New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(p1, p2, Color.Red, Color.Blue)
      g.FillRectangle(brsGradient, e.ClipRectangle)
      g.DrawImage(My.Resources.demoImage, Me.ClientRectangle.Location)
    End Using

  End Sub

  Private Sub frmBG_ResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.ResizeEnd
    Me.Invalidate()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: thanks by answer, but I want achieve a tiling background in a form. An alternative is create an image with huge resolution (2000X2000). But I think that should exist a simple and effective solution.